# Can a question be asked that has already an answer to a related question?

Tags: discussion, questions

Can the question [How long could a Oxygen/Nitrogen atmosphere last on the Moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/45406/how-long-could-a-oxygen-nitrogen-atmosphere-last-on-the-moon) be asked if it has [already an answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12576/could-the-moon-keep-an-atmosphere/12577#12577) to this [similar question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12576/could-the-moon-keep-an-atmosphere) ?

With just the key words "atmosphere" and "moon" the asker would have come easily upon [this answer.](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12576/could-the-moon-keep-an-atmosphere/12577#12577)

Answer (score 3):

I think I agree with uhoh that while that other question may technically have a simple answer to this new question, the answer to this new question includes details more specific to the question of "how long" that are understandably glossed over in the higher level question.

I do think there's still room here for an even more thorough answer as well. That being the case, I believe this question should remain open.

Comment: So i could ask the question "Could Mercury keep an atmosphere ?" despite the fact that that answer already answers it with the neat chart ? https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12576/could-the-moon-keep-an-atmosphere/12577#12577

Comment: @Cornelisinspace That depends. If your question was looking for a different level of detail than was available under that question, then yes you could.